# What's the difference between : 1. (ajaxStart and ajaxSend) and 2. (ajaxStop and ajaxComplete)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, loading

Basically that's the question (parentheses are important)

Comment: I was wondering the same based on the two different answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961438/implement-a-loading-indicator-for-a-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) are for *all* requests **together**, [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) fires when the *first* simultaneous request starts, [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) fires then the *last* of that simultaneous batch finishes.

So say you're making 3 requests all at once, `ajaxStart()` fires when the first starts, `ajaxStop()` fires when the last one (they don't necessarily finish in order) comes back.

These events *don't* get any arguments because they're for a batch of requests:

```
.ajaxStart( handler() )
.ajaxStop( handler() )
```

---

[`.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) fire once **per request** as they send/complete.  This is why these handlers are passed arguments and the global/batch ones are not:

```
.ajaxSend( handler(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) )
.ajaxComplete( handler(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) )
```

For a single documentation source, the [Global Ajax Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) section of [the API](http://api.jquery.com/) is what you're after.

Comment: this answer is very clear, worthy of being jQuery documentation in my opinion.

Comment: So basically, `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` are good for easy ways to, say, toggle a `loading` class on your document.

Comment: Feel free to extend this live exampe I started playing with http://jsfiddle.net/e4z9bv6k/

Comment: please someone correct the 2nd link in this answer as it takes me to a 404 page.