# catch all ajax requests in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm wanting to show a "Loading" progress bar every time an ajax request is sent. Is it possible to be notified ANYTIME an ajax request is sent using jQuery?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use the [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method to set global AJAX properties that will apply for the entire page:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        // show progress spinner
    },
    complete: function() {
        // hide progress spinner
    }
});
```

Comment: Will it catch even the ones that do not use jQeury or that's not possible?

Comment: @rain01, no, this will catch only jQuery AJAX requests.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov What about using on of those handlers directly? http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Answer (score 6):

For some reason or another [**`$.ajaxSetup()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) wasn't working for me. After reading through the [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) though, I found the following:

> Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective
>   global Ajax event handler methods—.ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(),
>   .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend()—rather than
>   within the options object for $.ajaxSetup().

Try [**`$.ajaxStart()`**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [**`$.ajaxComplete()`**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) instead:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    console.log('Request Initiated');
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    console.log('Request Complete');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using jQuery's [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) event

Comment: I would probably use `ajaxSend` instead as it is triggered for all the ajax requests (vs only the 1st one with `ajaxStart`). see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735877/whats-the-difference-between-1-ajaxstart-and-ajaxsend-and-2-ajaxstop-and

Comment: Another note: @LordZardeck might want to remove the "loading..." progress bar when all the ajax requests either finish successfully or with errors. That's something to be done using `.ajaxError()` and `.ajaxStop()`