# show bootstrap modal after content is loaded

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a Bootstrap 3 modal in which I load some data from a getJson function. Since the data inside the modal doesn't load equally fast I want to show a loading image/text. When all data is loaded then show/open the modal. I found this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961438/how-to-implement-a-loading-indicator-for-a-bootstrap-modal-waiting-for-ajax-to-f) which was quit usefull but I don't know how to place that inside my code. Can anybody help me with that?

My function

```
function myfunction(url){
  $('.products-loader').show(); //show the loading image and then??

  $.getJSON(url, function (data){

    var product = data.product;
    var image = 'http://www.webshop.com/i/' + image_id_convert(product.image) + '/380x380x2/image.jpg';

    $('.wqs-title').html('<a href="'+ product.url + '">' + product.title + '</a>');
    $('.wqs-description').html(product.description);
    $('.wqs-images').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');

    //etc....


  });   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bootstrap model object provides a manual show method. Let's assume it has the id `myModal`. Assuming you've set it up correctly and it's ready to be sprung, this is how you would display it once your data was ready:

```
function myfunction(url) {
  // Show progress bar
  $('.products-loader').show(); 

  // Make AJAX request to load data
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    // On success show modal
    $('#myModal').modal('show');

    // Do other stuff
  });   
}
```

For information on setting up your modal and other methods provided by the modal plugin, refer to the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: Ok thx... My modal is showing on a button click like so: `<div data-target="#webdinge-quick-shop-modal" class="quick-cart-trigger" data-toggle="modal"></div>`. Should I remove that and open it via jQuery?? It looks like the modal pops up even when the data isn't fully loaded.

Comment: You can configure it so that it is initially hidden by adding `data-show="false"`. Then you can open it as demonstrated above. See the Options section of the docs for more info.

Comment: thx a ton. Then this is exactly what I'm searching for. I've read the docs before but wasn't sure what the right approach would be!

Comment: I understand. I always experience a moment or two of cognitive dissonance when integrating Bootstrap with jQuery. Glad I could help.