# How can I get the requested url from ajaxStart function?

Tags: jquery

Can I get the requested URL from `ajaxStart` ? I want to execute a common action for all ajax request accept some few requests.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, within `ajaxStart` you do not have access to the `jqXHR` object nor the `ajaxOptions`:

```
// Watch for a new set of requests
if ( s.global && jQuery.active++ === 0 ) {
  jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStart" );
}
```

As you can see, there are no arguments being passed to `ajaxStart`. Contrast this with `ajaxSend`:

```
// Send global event
if ( fireGlobals ) {
  globalEventContext.trigger( "ajaxSend", [ jqXHR, s ] );
}
```

Where the `jqXHR` object is being passed as an argument along with the settings:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(evt, request, settings) {
  alert("Starting request at " + settings.url + ".");
});
```

Also see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735877/whats-the-difference-between-1-ajaxstart-and-ajaxsend-and-2-ajaxstop-and)** answer for a better understanding of this design.

Answer (score 11):

You cant get requested url from ajaxstart function,you can get only using ajaxsend function,because ajaxsend function regarding to the particular request but ajaxstart is not

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function( event, jqxhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/test.html" ) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSend handler." );
  }
});
```

Comment: You saved my day! This in combination with ajaxStop my universal REST call loading spinner is working like a charm! (method GET (loading), POST (saving), PUT (saving), DELETE (deleting) I owe you a beer!