# loading effect on different elements with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using AjaxStart and AjaxStop to create the loading effect on my Web Application. And it works fine.

But now I need to add the loading effect to another element and I don't know how to distinguish the ajax calls so that i'm able to control which element to apply the loading effect.

I know we can use the global property to prevent ajax requests to trigger ajaxStart/Stop but I need to set ajaxStart/Stop to different ajaxCalls

How can I do it?

Here's the code I'm using right now

```
var timer;
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("#main_content").LoadingOverlay("show");
        },
        1000);
    });


    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#main_content").LoadingOverlay("hide");
    });
```

Comment: track your current ajax request with a Global variable

Comment: but i need to differentiate each of them to load different elements

Comment: sometimes i need to load main_content other times other element

Comment: Sorry i did not really understand you

Comment: set an option on your ajax request and retrieve it in the ajaxSend method. and use ajaxComplete instead of ajaxstop ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735877/whats-the-difference-between-1-ajaxstart-and-ajaxsend-and-2-ajaxstop-and

Comment: Hello Christophe this is the answer indeed, Thanks. I cannot accept a comment though. If you answer I'll accept it. cheers